# Response from a API from RestTemplate needs to be passed to another in the request body. But it is failing with 400 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to pass the response of one API which may contain \n or quotes(") to another API using RestTemplate.

But it is always failing with 400 error. I guess the post body is broken because of newline and quotes in it.

Can you please suggest how to make it work?

This is the exception I am getting and my request body looks like:

{"to":"test@test.com","replyTo":"test@test.com","body":"call\n"}

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/endpoint/test, action: POST, status: 400
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:775)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:728)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:702)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.j
```

Comment: Can u get some fragmnet of code?

Comment: The best way to determine the actual cause of the problem is to log the response that you get from the first API then use insomnia, curl, postman or any other rest client to send it to the second API. Tha way you can manipulate it until you figure out whats causing the problem. Only after figuring the source of the problem can you be able to properly fix it

Comment: We are logging the response. And it seems it contains \n but it is possible that it can contain other escape sequences and quotes as well as we are sending the user chat in the request body.

Comment: @WBLord What part of the code you are actually referring to? It is a simple rest template API call.

Comment: Allow me to give you a challenge...... Share a request body that gives you 200 and also share the body that is giving you 500, I can help you compare them. I strongly suspect you are focusing of the 'wrong problem'

Comment: @PiagetHadzizi I have added the failing body in the question description. {"to":"test@test.com","replyTo":"test@test.com","body":"call\n"}. If you remove \n after call, it works fine.

Comment: now that's the problem, that means your endpoint doesn't allow newline character on the body. I will post my proposed solution......

Answer (score 0):

You need need to create a model like this:

```
class MyModel {
  String to;
  String replyTo;
  String body;
  //getters and setters......
}
```

marshal string into the object like this:

```
String requestBody="";//{"to":"test@test.com","replyTo":"test@test.com","body":"call\n"}
MyModel myModel=new ObjectMapper().readValue(requestBody, MyModel);
```

now that you have an object, remove newline characters from the body property. Like this:

```
String s=myModel.getBody().replace('\n', ' ');//you can choose to replace "\n" with whatever you want
myModel.setBody(s);
```

after that you can deserialise the object like this:

```
requestBody=new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myModel);
```

the send the `requestBody`